# Align detailTextLabel of UITableViewHeaderFooterView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, autolayout, uitableviewsectionheader

I got a `UITableView` and want to customize its sectionHeader. My goal is to have the **detailTextLabel right-Aligned** using Autolayout. (See Photo). Many hours I tried to set it's anchors, modified the `tableview.sectionHeaderHeight`, worked with the Headers contentView but I did not get it..

Can someone please show me a way how to properly manage this? Should I create a custom `UIView` and then add it to the `UITableViewHeaderFooterView`? How can I get the font-properties of the label then?

[image: Illustration]
*Created with Keynote*

---

My code looks like this, but I would not really use this as a starting point.. :)

```
class GSTableHeaderView: UITableViewHeaderFooterView, ReusableView {

  override init(reuseIdentifier: String?) {
    super.init(reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
  }

  func configure() {
    setupSubviews()
    setupConstraints()
  }

  func setupSubviews() {
    guard let detailTextLabel = detailTextLabel, let textLabel = textLabel else { return }
    contentView.addSubview(detailTextLabel)
  }

  func setupConstraints() {
    guard let detailTextLabel = detailTextLabel, let textLabel = textLabel else { return }
    detailTextLabel.anchor(top: nil, leading: nil, bottom: contentView.bottomAnchor, trailing: contentView.trailingAnchor, paddingTop: 0, paddingLeading: 0, paddingBottom: 0, paddingTrailing: 16, width: 0, height: 0)
    detailTextLabel.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: textLabel.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
  }

  required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
  }
}
```

---

```
lazy var tableView: UITableView = {
    let tableview = UITableView(frame: .zero, style: .grouped)
    tableview.dataSource = self
    tableview.delegate = self
    tableview.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
    tableview.rowHeight = 44
    tableview.sectionHeaderHeight = 70
    tableview.estimatedSectionHeaderHeight = 70
    tableview.isScrollEnabled = false
    tableview.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    tableview.register(GSAltDetailTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: GSAltDetailTableViewCell.reuseIdentifier)
    tableview.register(GSTableHeaderView.self, forHeaderFooterViewReuseIdentifier: GSTableHeaderView.reuseIdentifier)
    return tableview
}()

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let header = tableView.dequeueReusableHeaderFooterView(withIdentifier: GSTableHeaderView.reuseIdentifier) as! GSTableHeaderView
    header.textLabel?.text = "Details"
    header.detailTextLabel?.text = "Expand all"
    header.tag = section

    header.configure()
    return header
}
```

Comment: How have you created the current view? show your code

Comment: I have tried so many things I literally don't now which point I should show. The picture is made with Keynote. Added some code now.

Answer (score 1):

Create CustomSectionHeaderView with xib file:
[image]

Your class:

```
class CustomSectionHeaderView: UIView {

    @IBOutlet weak var titleLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var detailLabel: UILabel!

    class func fromNib() -> CustomSectionHeaderView {
        return UINib(nibName: String(describing: self), bundle: nil).instantiate(withOwner: nil, options: nil)[0] as! CustomSectionHeaderView
    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

    }
}
```

In ViewContoller:

```
var headerSectionView = CustomSectionHeaderView.fromNib()

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {

    headerSectionView.titleLabel.text = "TITLE"
    headerSectionView.detailLabel.text = "DETAILS"

    //or if you need 
    //headerSectionView.detailLabel.isHidden = true

    return headerSectionView
}
```

Comment: I am not using storyboard, but how do I get the properties of the Labels?

Comment: If you don't want create xib file use this approach. But before that, create labels and add constraints programmatically.